# Siebel Open UI - How to make a query over Business Component from Javascript

Tags: sapui5, siebel

I'm struggling to a Siebel Open UI requirement which ask for running a query over the current Business Component upon a double click on a record.

I tried the following in PR js associated to my custom applet:

```
 var pm = this.GetPM();                                                                                                 
 var recordSet = pm.Get("GetRecordSet");
 for (record in recordSet) {
 var row = $("#" + this.GetPM().Get("GetPlaceholder"))
  .find("tr[id=" + (Number(record) + 1) + "]")
  .dblclick({ctx:pm}, function(event) {
  var bc = event.data.ctx.Get("GetBusComp"); 
  bc.InvokeMethod("ClearToQuery");
  bc.SetSearchSpec("Id","1-81OR");
  bc.InvokeMethod("ExecuteQuery");  
}); 
}
```

the "bc" variable seems to be corrected instantiated, but when I look in the method exposed (console web browser) I don't see any of interest for making a query apart from InvokeMethod("ExecuteQuery") which is not working (it does nothing when I look at the logs).

Do you know how can I make such query from PR or PM?

Vincenzo

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations in earlier versions of OpenUi but after 15, it has exposure to many BC methods.
Try this:
http://www.askmesiebel.com/2014/04/siebel-open-ui-invoke-business-service-from-pm-file/

Comment: Dave, please edit to summarize the relevant information from that link in your answer; Stack Overflow answers should encapsulate enough detail that a dead link doesn't render them useless. Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it, Query itselft is not possible on browser side. Only way is to call a Business Service which performs the query (at that time, bs is executed on the servver side)